# How can I change the fontsize of colorbar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Here's the code I have:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cm, norm=plt.Normalize(0, cycles - 1)), ticks=np.arange(cycles), label='cycles',location = 'bottom') 
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
```

And the output looks like
[image]
I can make the ticks have the size I want to be, but is there a way I can also change the font size of 'cycles' here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This two-liner can be used with any Text property (http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text)

```
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label(label='a label',weight='bold')
```

or:

plt.colorbar().set_label(label='a label',size=15,weight='bold')